# Custom section (e.g. Demos or Downloads)

Tags: customization

On my website, I want to display a page where I will store all my demos, which should function just like a blog (so I can add new records, edit them and specify custom meta data and list all of them on a public page), but it should independent for easier management. I have searched the web for answers or tutorials, but haven't any.

Example can be found here: http://css-tricks.com/downloads/

As you can see there there is a separate blog and the demos page function as an independent group of records, with their special metadata and I'm pretty sure there is a way of creating something like this.

Comment: It's not a separate blog, it's just the Demos page from http://css-tricks.com/. "Independent" is a bit vague here.

Comment: @Patrick sorry for that, I just didn't know how to describe it exactly. Anyway, your answer have answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: @timbo-kz It's fine, just making sure I understood you well. I added the WP_Query documentation to the answer if you want to know how to loop the custom post types in your page template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a page template and register a custom post type with its own categories, tags and pretty much everything. You then loop these custom post type entries in your custom template page.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query